# Providing wrong answer with if-else inside function on R?

Tags: r

```
myfun <- function(ret,d,tau,n){
    area<-0
    for(i in d) { 
        ifelse(i < tau + ret, area <- area + (ret-i)^n,0)
    }
    return(data.frame(area=area,tau=tau,ret=ret))
}
```

Now   `myfun(c(-10,11),c(6,4,5),3,1)` gives the answer as `-45` and `18`.
But for `myfun(c(-10,-11),c(6,4,5),3,1)` answer is `0` and `0`. 
For `ret= -10` answer should be zero which was provided only in 2nd case. 
Where is the error for such misleading answer?

Comment: Your function somehow looks very strange. Why do you write area <- 0 before and why dont you write, area <- 0 for the else part of the ifelse? Generally, I would use the standard if () {} else {} in this case and not ifelse...ifelse returns a value i.e. a <- ifelse(x > y, x, y).

Comment: Won't `tau + ret` give you a vector of length 2 where you really want a scalar?